# Unable to run Jug in windows

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use Jug for parallel processing. I have a Canopy installed and I also installed Jug using command `pip install jug` according to the documentation online.

In order to find where jug is installed, I installed jug again using the same command as above, it showed
me:

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jug in
>   c:\users[userfolder]\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>   (from jug)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in
>   c:\users[userfolder]\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>   (from jug)
>
> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): redis in
>   c:\users[userfolder]\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages
>   (from jug)

Now, I thought my jug is in the path of `c:\users\[userfolder]\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-package` and it is there since I listed all files under this folder and I saw it.

I am not sure this jug is a exe or py or something else, but I tried to run a command: `jug C:\primes.py` under this folder, it gave me error message said jug is not a recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file....

I also tried the command `./jug C:\primes.py` and `.\jug C:\primes.py`, but none of them works.

In addition, I tried `python jug status C:\primes.py` and this one gave me message of `cannot find '_main_' module in 'jug'`.

Now I have no idea how to run jug. Has someone ever tried jug on windows could help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. It is related to python's relative import.

Comment: I'm having the same problem now - but I don't really understand "It is related to python's relative import." How did you solve this?